# Object data member --set null or don't set at all, or create new object for different data members?

Tags: php, class, object

I'm trying to use one php object on several different types of post. Each type of post has several extra data members that the others don't have. The object will need some service from other classes that will check `if( $something instanceof $object )`. So,using extends may not work, and I'm trying to use one class for all.  In the object class, should I list all possible data members as default and set the unused ones as null, or ignore the unused ones?

for example

```
class OBJ{

  // common members that share among all posts:
    public $id;
    public $url;
    public $embed_service

  //post has grade
    public $link_grade;

  //posts has license
    public $license;

  //posts has corresponding topics  
    public $comment_topic_id;

//different types of data comes from different actions, saved in one table.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is using *inheritance* and derive different types of post from a common object:

```
class Post
{
  protected $Content = 'enter content';
}

class Blog extends Post
{
  protected $Categorie;
}

class Comment extends Post
{
  protected email;
}
```

The result of this is:

- all classes have a `Content` property
- the blog class has a extra `Category` property
- the comment class has a extra `email`  property

Comment: currently in my template, I display different stuffs like this: if $object->content=='this' do_this() ; if $object->content=='that' do_that(); So, I should stop do_this or do_that, instead, use the extends class? It's just better or I was wrong?

Comment: just edited. the display part is simple, for example, if it's post, display media components, if it's forum topic, display voting arrows.

Comment: While editing my question, I noticed that my data members are quote un-related. But all post share the same embed service which is a big block. In addition, it's just very convenient to loop through post and display one object. If multi objects, may need several loops.